# Find a bound for $\Vert A^{-1} \Vert_{\infty}$ and $\Vert A^{-1} \Vert_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the matrix below

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 6 & 1 & 1 & 0 & & \cdots & & & 0 \\
1 & 6 & 1 & 1 & 0 & & & & \vdots \\
1 & 1 & 6 & 1 & 1 & 0 & & & \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 6 & 1 & 1 & & & 0 \\
\vdots & & & & & & & & 1 \\
  & & & & & 1 & 1 & 6 & 1 \\
0 & & \cdots & & & 0 & 1 & 1 & 6
\end{bmatrix}$$
Show $A$ is non-singular and find a bound for $\Vert A^{-1} \Vert_{\infty}$ and $\Vert A^{-1} \Vert_2$.

Comment: Hint: consider $\|6I - A\|$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks for your guide, I solved this problem by your guide and one special theorem.

Comment: What special theorem might that be?

Comment: Let $A$ and $B$ be square matrices of the same order. Assume $B$ is non-singular and suppose that $\Vert B - A \Vert \leqslant \frac{1}{\Vert B^{-1} \Vert}$, Then $A$ is also non-singular and $\Vert A^{-1} \Vert \leqslant \frac{\Vert B^{-1}\Vert}{1-\Vert B^{-1} \Vert \Vert B - A \Vert}$.

Comment: By your guide, Let $B = 6I$, $B^{-1} = \frac{1}{6} I$. Since $\Vert B - A \Vert_{\infty} = 4 \leqslant \frac{1}{\Vert B^{-1} \Vert_{\infty} } = 6 $, then by this theorem, $A$ is a non-singular matrix and we can find a bound for both $\Vert A^{-1} \Vert_{\infty}$ and $\Vert A^{-1} \Vert_2$ as mentioned in the theorem above.

Comment: Well, to be sure, my work is a derivation of the theorem you mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\|A^{-1}\| = \\
\frac 16\left\|\left(I - \left(I - \frac 16 A\right)\right)^{-1}\right\| = \\
\frac 16 \left\|
\sum_{k=0}^\infty
\left(I - \frac 16 A\right)^{k}
\right\| \leq\\
\frac 16 
\sum_{k=0}^\infty
\left\|I - \frac 16 A
\right\|^k =\\
\frac 16 \frac{1}{1 - \|I - A/6\|} = \\
\frac{1}{6 - \|6I - A\|}
$$